# The media Print wont work on all of the modals in the table

Tags: php, html, css

I have a modal on each tenant on a table for their receipt and i only want to print the modal, but the problem is the print only works on the first tenant, and does not work on the other tenants on the table.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
    var modThis = document.querySelector("#printSection .modifyMe");
    modThis.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
    window.print();
}
function printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
}
</script>

  (html)
  <div id="printThis" class=" modifyMe">
  <h3 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">


(css)
@media print {
body * {
visibility:hidden;
}
#printSection, #printSection * {
visibility:visible;
}
#printSection {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to see properly with the limited parts of code you're showing here. In particular the loop that creates your modals in the table would help. From what I can see, it looks like you are selecting the element by id, but using a generic id `printThis`. If that same ID is repeated across all the modals, it might be the issue,

Comment: @Luke yeah, i think the ID is the issue

Comment: any update? Did changing the ID fix the issue?